# Conditional iterations constant.

Tags: closed-form, recursion

Let $f(0)=2.$
Define for positive integers $n$ :

$f(n+1) = \frac{3}{2} f(n)$ if $f(n)$ is even.

$f(n+1) = \frac{3}{2}(f(n)+1)$ if $f(n)$ is odd.

We now have $\lim_{n->\infty} \dfrac{4* (3/2)^{n} }{f(n)} = C$

Where $C$ is some constant.

Apparantly $C$~$\sqrt[11] {10}$ but I guess that $C$ can not be exactly that value ?

What is the closed form for $C$ ?

Comment: Its easy to prove that $C > 1.$
This follows from the fact that $4 * (3/2)^n$ is a good asymptotic for the recursion $g(0)=2$,$g(n+1) = \frac{3}{2}(g(n)+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did  not find a closed form, but you are correct that $C\ne10^{1/11}$.

If $f(n)$ is even
$$
\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=\frac32\tag{1}
$$
If $f(n)$ is odd
$$
\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=\frac32\left(1+\frac1{f(n)}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{f(n)}{f(0)}=\left(\frac32\right)^n\prod_{\substack{k=0\\f(k)\text{ is odd}}}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1{f(k)}\right)\tag{3}
$$
Since $f(n)\ge\left(\frac32\right)^n$, the product in $(3)$ converges.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
C
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{f(n)}\left(\frac32\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{f(0)}\left[\prod_{\substack{k=0\\f(k)\text{ is odd}}}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1{f(k)}\right)\right]^{-1}\\
&=2\left[\prod_{\substack{k=0\\f(k)\text{ is odd}}}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{f(k)}\right)\right]^{-1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Computing $C$ using $n=120$ in $(4)$, I get
$$
C=1.2328400204796570012\tag{5}
$$
which is accurate to $20$ places. The ISC finds nothing for this number.

Note that
$$
10^{1/11}=1.2328467394420661391\tag{6}
$$

Comment: I wonder if we can tell how often $f(k)$ is odd for $k$ between $0$ and some positive integer $X$.
Maybe that can be expressed in terms of $X$ and $C$.

Comment: Even if we could say $1/2$, which I think is likely, the positioning of them is more important than the frequency.